# Show column on desktop, trigger column on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have [here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/01991tj3/) is 2 columns with 50% each, this will be a desktop layout. Now on mobile viewport, usualy we just make the columns 100%, in my case, the `right` column should hide. And only be shown when is triggered by the link in the `left` column. How can I do that? Because I have no clue.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col left">
    <p><a href="#">Expand Right Column on mobile only</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col right">
    <p>Content to be showed on desktop and expanded on mobile via trigger above</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .left, .right {
        width: 100%;

    }
    .right{display: none;}
}
```

This should do it add display:none;

**Edit1:** To show the hidden div use this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col left">
        <p><button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('right').style.display = 'block'">
Click Me!</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col right">
        <p>Content to be showed on desktop and expanded on mobile via trigger above</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01991tj3/1/)

**Edit2:** [JSFiddle to toggle the display attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/01991tj3/2/)

Comment: ok, now I get it. But what if I want to hide it again? how can I do that?